# Android Studioで実機が認識されない

Tags: android

先ほど、Android Studioで突然実機が認識されなくなりました。
今まではつながっていたのですが。。。

USBケーブルを変えてもダメだったのですが何かわかる方いましたら教えてください。

Comment: 認識されていた時と、認識されなくなった後の間に行った事（ソフトウェア、ハードウェア（ケーブル交換なども含む）などなど）を明らかにしてください。　単に実機がスリープ状態になったとか等ではないのですよね？

Answer (score 3):

１、Android端末を再起動
２、"adb server-kill"と"adb server-start"
この二つをしてみて反応しませんかね？

この場合疑うべきは

- ADB（端末側、AndroidStudio側）
- Android端末側がデバッグONじゃなくなっている（たまーに設定が内部動作によって書き換えられることあり）
- USBケーブル二つ
- ドライバー（Win環境なら）
- ポートが物理的に破損している
- AndroidStudioのADBインテグレーション設定がオフになっている（追加）

かなーと思います。

---

追記：

- AndroidStudioのADBインテグレーションの確認と設定方法について

AndroidStudioのメニューの`"Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration"`にチェックが入っているか確認してください。チェックが入っていないなら、メニューをクリックしてください。
その後AndroidStudioの下の方にあるAndroidMonitorにあるプルダウンから接続しているデバイスを選択するとログなりが出るようになります。